# inner for loop is executed only once

Tags: python-3.x, nested

I am writing `python3` code to read file called `loopback.txt` and then compare every entry in that file with all entries in another file called `sid.txt`, if the entry in sid found it will print it otherwise continue, the problem that the code only check first entry in loopback file and then inner loop executed and outer loop executed only once.

```
flooback=open('loopback.txt')
fsid=open('sid.txt')
count=0
for line in flooback:
    line=line.strip()
    for sid in fsid:
        sid=sid.strip()
        if sid==line:
            print(sid)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilies:

- open `sid.txt` for each row from `loopback.txt`, not just once in the beginning, otherwise the inner for-loop will always start at the end of the file, doing nothing
- if the data size ist not that large you can read the smaller file into a python `list` so you don't have to read it for each row of the other file
- depending on your data you can also read the smaller file into a python `dict` which can make it faster to check if some line is contained in it

And there are certainly more efficient approaches depending on your data and what you you actually want to achive.